# Noise on AD converters only while powering relays

Tags: adc

I am reading a 5V analog signal from an ACS 724 current sensor. When I have zero current it idles at 127 on 8bit ADC or 511 on 10bit ADC. Both the Arduino board and a Velleman USB board jumps around when I switch on 5V relays through PNP transistors.

The readings on my voltage divider do not jump around as much and provide meaningful readings, but the ACS 724 readings are totally unusable when the relays are switched, upto 10% jitter.

I have verified that the ACS 724 is measuring correctly by applying current through it with a bench supply and measuring + calibrating, it works well.

Obviously the relays are causing the problem. I need some advice to stabilise the ACS 724 as it needs to measure the current passing through the relays

I have attached some photos of the prototype:

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Show schematic and layout. Sounds like decoupling issue.

Comment: Thank you what software do you recommend for linux to draw schematics? Its just off the shelf boards connected 5V dc-dc converter powering the relays which are switched with PNP resistors. Im busy teaching myself electronics and coding

Comment: KiCad. You can just click on edit here and click on the schematic symbol. An editor will open up. “It’s just” sounds like you don’t have any decoupling capacitors.

Comment: Cool just installed KiCad - do you suggest i solder some capacitors over the relay powering coils to test

Comment: If the problem occurs constantly when the relays are on, then it's not due to switching. Could be a grounding issue, but it's hard to see because the boards are on top of each other. The first thing to do would be to send a known constant current through the relay and ACS724, to make sure it's not the load drawing a varying current, like a motor would. I'm not sure I understand the question correctly. Is the current measured by ACS724 switched by the relays, or are the relays switching an unrelated circuit?

Comment: If ACS724 is not monitoring the current switched by the relay, then try to determine if the problem is caused by the relay on the coil side (switch it without any load) or on the load side (switch it with load, and put the load on the NC contact so it is on when the relay is off). Then you'll have more info.

Comment: the noise happens with no load attached, just having the relays switched on with nothing connected through them. The idea is the ACS724 measures the current passing through the relays eventually. Everything has a common ground on the 5V dc-dc supply.

Comment: Whatever Vcc/5V/12V or similar needs capacitor(s) to ground as close to whatever is loading it.

Comment: And Ground as good "star wiring" ....

Comment: Is it possible, that the ACS724 just "sees" the magnetic field of a relay directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in comment by Jens,

> Is it possible, that the ACS724 just "sees" the magnetic field of a relay directly? – Jens

Edit: I found [this](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-TLI4971_Strayfield_AppNote-ApplicationNotes-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462700c0ae601703503e2ac1b42) for some pieces of info.

Yes,
I think it is possible.
Datasheet:

- Primary Hall Coupling Factor G1 TA = 25°C – 11 – G/A,
- Secondary Hall Coupling Factor G2 TA = 25°C – 2.8 – G/A,
- Common Mode Field Rejection Ratio **CMFRR Uniform external magnetic field – 40 – dB**.

Don't know what are G1 & G2.

To be convinced, take an electro-magnet (DIY) and approach near the IC, and see if measurement changes.

Eventually, use an "iron cage" to "lock" external magnetic fields..
This [site](https://www.magnetic-shield.com/all-about-shielding-faqs/) can be useful.

> How Do Magnetic Shields Work?
> Magnetic shielding materials re-direct a magnetic field so it
> lessens the field's influence on the item being shielded.
> Shielding does not eliminate or destroy magnetic fields,
> nothing does.
> It does, however, provide an easy path for the magnetic field to complete its path.
> You may think of it as a magnetic field conductor.

In this [datasheet acs70331](https://www.allegromicro.com/en/products/sense/current-sensor-ics/zero-to-fifty-amp-integrated-conductor-sensor-ics/acs70331), reference to external fields ...

> Maximum **Continuous** External Field [3](https://www.allegromicro.com/en/products/sense/current-sensor-ics/zero-to-fifty-amp-integrated-conductor-sensor-ics/acs70331) B **±50 G** .

See this paragraph : **Current Sensing Method using GMR and
Stray Field Immunity**, page 12.

Comment: Thank you very much for these ideas how to fix, i have put decoupling capacitors on the relays to no effect, and now i have scrapped the idea to use ACS724 module.